# How to get the result from an ASyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to connect to a host in my local network. Reaching it works from my computer or my android phone (SGS2) and it seems it also works from withing my app, but I want to get a result to check if it worked and depending on that proceed with further actions.

I am using an implementation of ASyncTask, named Connector.
When I call Connector I don't just call execute but also get() in order to receive a boolean value denoting the success. The problem here is that execute performs fine (the host is definitely reached and I land at my breakpoints in doInBackground.

But how can I receive the boolean value which I return in doInBackground?
When I call get() it never finishes...

Basically, what I care about is the variable "connected", but get() seems to run perpetuously! 
Permissions are granted in the manifest, wifi on my phone is enabled and works, I can reach the host.

This is where I execute Connector:

```
url = new URL("http://192.168.2.103/?LED=T");
            Connector connector = new Connector();
            AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Boolean> execute = connector
                    .execute(url);
            Status status = execute.getStatus();
            boolean connected = false;
            try {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "trying to get result");
                connected = connector.get();
                Log.d("MainActivity", "got result");
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //do something depending on connected
```

And this is Connector:

```
public class Connector extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Boolean> {

public static boolean connect(URL url) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
    System.out.println();

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(URL... params) {
    boolean connect = connect(params[0]);

    return connect;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Log.d("Connector", "onPostExecute");
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

Comment: Using the `get()` method of `AsyncTask` is completely pointless. It turns an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one and will basically block the thread you call it from. If this is from an `Activity`, this will block the main(UI) thread and will cause problems building the UI (depending on where you call it from) and may potentially cause an ANR situation. You should make your `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `Activity` as codeMagic suggests then you can manipulate UI components from the `onPostExecute(...)` method of the `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to call `get()` since you have already run the AsyncTask with `execute()`. If you just want to see that the connected variable is being set then use a `Lof` in your `onPostExecute()` since the result from `doInBackground` is sent to it. If you need to do something with it then you can do that in `onPostExecute()` as well

Comment: I need "connected" where I call connector.execute(), because depending on its state I would like to print messages to the user or change button icons etc

Comment: If your Async is an inner class to your calling class and connected is a field variable in the main class then you will have access to it in your async. Otherwise you can call a method in your calling class that sets that variable through `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I considered that but was a bit hesitating since from an OOP-point of view connected as a field would not be a characteristic of the activity, it's an attribute of Connector. However, this definitely works. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really take away from the OO part, it just makes it more visible to be used by the inner class. Glad I could help. If its working for you, could you kindly accept the answer :)